# How can i get a categories tree view in alphabetical order without to lose the tree structure

Tags: mysql

I use for my component a categories table like the categories table from Joomla. 
So the structure has also the columns from the Joomla categories table:
- Table jos_my_categories structure: id, parent_id, lft, rgt, level, title ...

Normally is use for the default sort order:
    $query->order('c.lft');
which gives a result as example (only categories titles):

- beta

  - charly
  - alpha
  - beta
- alpha

  - beta
  - - zulu
  - - sierra
  - charly
  - alpha
- charly

  - alpha
  - beta
  - charly

But required is alternate also a tree result in alpbabetical order (also for the sub categories - in all levels):

- alpha

  - alpha
  - beta
  - - sierra
  - - zulu
  - charly
- beta

  - alpha
  - beta
  - charly
- charly

  - alpha
  - beta
  - charly

How must in this case be the query?

Answer (score 2):

I m just trying to answer. You can try

```
$query->order('c.lft,c.name ASC');
```

If you can provide the Complete Query or code then you might get the exact answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But this has not helped. The 'lft' column can only have 'unique' values.

Comment: Okay i have find out that it is not possible to sort alphabetical nested sets. So i must use a own sort method. So we can close my question.

Comment: When anybody else search the solution, here can you find it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20448404/3319544